# Passing an array of strings to Parse.com REST API query

Tags: jquery

The "$in" method expects an array and the column in question is a string so I need to go from this using jQuery:

```
[123,456,789]
```

to this:

```
["123,"456","789"]
```

Comment: So... are you asking how to convert an array of numbers to an array of strings?

Comment: YES!! Simple I'm know but I'm banging away and haven't gotten it :/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I don't think it needs much of an explanation:

```
arr = $.map(arr, function(val) { return val.toString(); });
```

If you have floating point values instead of integers, you might want to use the [`.toFixed` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method instead of calling `.toString()`.